# Mule - Generate Payload in JSON format from HashMap <String, String> in the following format

Tags: mule, esb, mulesoft

Mule 3.9: How to generate the payload in JSON format from the HashMap type.

Transform the HashMap type  payload to JSON array format. The sample data of HashMap

Key:  Value
MK1 : T1
MK2 : T2
MK3 : T3

Target format to generate in Mule from DataWeave 1.0

```
{
  "cars": [
    {
      "makeId": "MK1",
      "makeName": "T1"
    },
    {
      "makeId": "MK2",
      "makeName": "T2"
    },
    {
      "makeId": "MK3",
      "makeName": "T3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to covert the HashMap of key and value (both string type) to be converted to the above defined JSON array format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script produces the expected result:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    "cars": payload pluck { 
        makeId: $, 
        makeName: $$ 
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "cars": [
    {
      "makeId": "T1",
      "makeName": "MK1"
    },
    {
      "makeId": "T3",
      "makeName": "MK3"
    },
    {
      "makeId": "T2",
      "makeName": "MK2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After working out a few details about map operator in Mule dataweave, i was able to resolve the issue using the below transformer.

%dw 1.0

### %output application/json

"cars": 
    payload map { 
               makeId: $, 
               makeName: $$ }

Comment: This answer doesn't provides the expected result. In a map operation '$$' returns the index of the key (a number), not its value.

Comment: Same for me, it is just returning id index, regardless from key' actual string value.